# What are some journals where the papers employ technical logic and math notation?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-philosophy

Recently, I have been interested in philosophy papers that employ technical logic and/or math notation. I know of analytic philosophy, but I am looking specifically for papers that use technical notation, which not all analytic philosophy papers do. Are there philosophy journals where the majority of papers in those journals use logical and mathematical notation, and if so, can someone give me several recommendations?

Comment: [Synthese](https://www.springer.com/journal/11229), [Analysis](https://academic.oup.com/analysis), [Erkenntis](https://www.springer.com/journal/10670) have quite a bit of logical and mathematical notation in their published articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many philosophers like to use formal logic in their work, though many do not. You might do better to follow some particular philosophers whose work you are interested in.

In terms of particular journals, Journal of Philosophical Logic, Journal of Applied Logic and Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic come to mind. But you will also find logic-heavy articles in various other philosophical journals, including Philosophical Review, Journal of Philosophy, Noûs, Analysis, Mind, Proceedings of the Aristotelian Society, Synthese, Erkenntnis, and many others. And sometimes you will find some articles of philosophical interest in journals such as Studia Logica, Journal of Symbolic Logic, Bulletin of Symbolic Logic, Review of Symbolic Logic, etc.

Comment: In the analytic tradition. It think formal logic is much less prominent in the continental tradition of philosophy.